# How to display labels on axes in 3d surface plot using google charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I am drawing a 3d surface plot using google charts API. I want labels on axes. Can anyone help me, to get the labels?
Is there any property for this?

Comment: The Google Charts API doesn't support 3D surfaces. Can you post a little code so I can see what you're doing, and maybe I can help?

Comment: You can take following example as an example of what I am drawing.     http://javascript-surface-plot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleVizApi.html

Comment: Okay, this isn't Google's charting API. This is a project that's hosted at GoogleCode, Google's code hosting platform. I would contact the author of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I ported Greg Ross's excellent JS 3D library to google script. Here is a link to the working plot. In order to set the title for the axes, change the values in lines 53, 54 and 55 of file JS3D.js.html of the attached project.

working example hosted on Google Apps script: [JS 3D Plot](http://bit.ly/1PDDDv1)
(Try in any browser except MS IE or Edge)

The GAS project can be found here: [JS-3D-Plot](https://github.com/electronicsguy/MereScripts/tree/master/Google-Apps/JS-3D-Plot)

All credit goes to Greg Ross ([gregross](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javascript-surface-plot/))